# How to make IpTable Rules immutable in linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, iptables, netfilter

I work on Linux and want to add rules to iptable. I want these rules to be immutable anyway (either changed or deleted). What should I do? Note that for me the rules that are running and kept in memory are important, not the rules that are stored in the iptable rules file.

I found a way to save the rules in a file and compare them with the rules backup file and detect the changes, but it's not a good way, I think it's too slow and there are ways to bypass this check.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as the iptables tag states: IPTABLES SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com. Use this tag only for questions on programming with iptables. Questions about configuring iptables should be asked on Server Fault (https://serverfault.com/). Please delete this.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but it's not about configuration. There is no command for this or There is no checkbox to make the rules immutable, I think it's about writing a kernel module.

Comment: If you don't have root access, you can't change iptables. If you do have root access, you can change anything, including the kernel module preventing you from changing iptables. So your question has no answer.